# Stylesheet Loading On Codeignitor

Tags: html, css, codeigniter-3

I have made a website in `codeignitor` framework using a preexisting theme, everything works fine but i have diagnosed a strange problem.

> When i use HTTP on my website and open this link
>   http://sevenhillsmanali.com/assets/css/style.css
>
> But when i open same link on HTTPs it serves a every different CSS
>   file https://sevenhillsmanali.com/assets/css/style.css

CSS file loaded via http is the original css file, the file loaded on https protocol is css file of last website hosted on this server which is completely deleted.

The astonishing part of everything is that there is no file called "Style.css" on this destination `/assets/css/style.css` which i have manually checked from cpanel.

Can someone diagnose and explain me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS files are **cached**, clear your cache and try to open it again.

For me, I can't access any of your files.

Comment: I used Mobile, Different browser file is still accessible for me, ok let me try something more

Comment: I am not able to access files when i used a VPN , its says 404 error, does ISP too cache files ?